# Increase font sizes for property names and values

Tags: interface, customization, font

Using Blender 2.92.0

It seems this issue is kind of interesting.   I've adjusted the font  sizes to where they seem usable for me, great :)   However loading up a saved file *.blend file and the UI elements in Blender itself get changed.    Is there a way to get Blender to not resize its own UI settings when loading a drawing?  Or save off the portion of the UI settings and only load them or merge/replace them in the saved drawing file?

Expected:
Blender's UI fonts remain to a user's settings/preferences.

Actual:
New drawing just selecting General from startup splash screen (desired settings)
[image]

Open saved drawing:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the *Resolution Scale* factor instead of adjusting font sizes? Your UI should look less wonky if you adjust the scale that way.

Answer (score 1):

To stop loaded files from changing your preferences, go to User Preferences under *Edit* > *Preferences* and under the *Save & Load* category, look for the **Load UI** checkbox. Uncheck it.

[image]

Then, while still in *Preferences*, go to the *Interface* category and click in the **Resolution Scale** text field. Enter a new value for the scale. You will want it to be some value greater than 1.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  While i'm not a huge fan of the "Scale All" as the resolution size does.  If you only need to size the font, why increase padding and dead space, just takes usable screen space and decreases the overall display.